# CCNet - no way to logically invert triggers?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I have the following triggers configured so that a successful build of either project A or project B will trigger this project (C):

```xml
<triggers>
  <multiTrigger operator="And">
    <triggers>
      <multiTrigger operator="Or">
        <triggers>
          <projectTrigger serverUri="tcp://localhost:21235/CruiseManager.rem" project="A" >
            <triggerFirstTime>False</triggerFirstTime>
            <triggerStatus>Success</triggerStatus>
            <innerTrigger type="intervalTrigger" seconds="60" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
          </projectTrigger>
          <projectTrigger serverUri="tcp://localhost:21235/CruiseManager.rem" project="B">
            <triggerFirstTime>False</triggerFirstTime>
            <triggerStatus>Success</triggerStatus>
            <innerTrigger type="intervalTrigger" seconds="60" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
          </projectTrigger>
        </triggers>
      </multiTrigger>
      <scheduleTrigger time="20:30" buildCondition="ForceBuild">
        <weekDays>
          <weekDay>Monday</weekDay>
          <weekDay>Tuesday</weekDay>
          <weekDay>Wednesday</weekDay>
          <weekDay>Thursday</weekDay>
          <weekDay>Friday</weekDay>
        </weekDays>
      </scheduleTrigger>
    </triggers>
  </multiTrigger>
</triggers>
```

However, what I actually want is project C to build only if the last build of BOTH projects A and B was successful. I thought something like the following would work, BUT there doesn't appear to be any way to logically invert a projectTrigger.

```xml
<triggers>
  <multiTrigger operator="And">
    <triggers>
      <multiTrigger operator="Or">
        <triggers>
          <projectTrigger serverUri="tcp://localhost:21235/CruiseManager.rem" project="A" >
            <triggerFirstTime>False</triggerFirstTime>
            <triggerStatus>Success</triggerStatus>
            <innerTrigger type="intervalTrigger" seconds="60" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
          </projectTrigger>
          <projectTrigger serverUri="tcp://localhost:21235/CruiseManager.rem" project="B">
            <triggerFirstTime>False</triggerFirstTime>
            <triggerStatus>Success</triggerStatus>
            <innerTrigger type="intervalTrigger" seconds="60" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
          </projectTrigger>
        </triggers>
      </multiTrigger>
      <projectTrigger serverUri="tcp://localhost:21235/CruiseManager.rem" project="A" >
        <triggerFirstTime>False</triggerFirstTime>
        <triggerStatus>NotFailure</triggerStatus>
        <innerTrigger type="intervalTrigger" seconds="60" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
      </projectTrigger>
      <projectTrigger serverUri="tcp://localhost:21235/CruiseManager.rem" project="B">
        <triggerFirstTime>False</triggerFirstTime>
        <triggerStatus>NotFailure</triggerStatus>
        <innerTrigger type="intervalTrigger" seconds="60" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
      </projectTrigger>
      <scheduleTrigger time="20:30" buildCondition="ForceBuild">
        <weekDays>
          <weekDay>Monday</weekDay>
          <weekDay>Tuesday</weekDay>
          <weekDay>Wednesday</weekDay>
          <weekDay>Thursday</weekDay>
          <weekDay>Friday</weekDay>
        </weekDays>
      </scheduleTrigger>
    </triggers>
  </multiTrigger>
</triggers>
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

CC.net seems not to provide a way of negating trigger logic. Understandable, considering that triggers tell CC.net when to execute source control blocks (checking for modifications) and start integration. However you could use a **`sourcecontrol`** block with **`type="external"`** , it allows you to use your own executables to decide whether to start integration or not.

At times I have also used the file system source control block to start integration when a certain file changes. For example when `c:\onsuccess\success.txt` used to indicate Success, has been updated.

```
<sourcecontrol type="filesystem">
   <repositoryRoot>c:\onsuccess</repositoryRoot>
   <ignoreMissingRoot>true</ignoreMissingRoot>
 </sourcecontrol>
```

**Addendum**: Link to [relevant documentation](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/External)

Comment: My understanding is that this would require both A and B to successfully build since the last build of C in order for C to be triggered. However, the requirement is that EITHER A OR B build successfully, and that NEITHER A NOR B have failed. The first part should be covered, the second is the problem.

Comment: you tried? I can probably achieve this effect using sourcecontrol blocks, see my edited answer above.